# Speed up git-fetch-pack?

Tags: git, bitbucket

We have hundreds of thousands of refs in our repo (self-hosted bitbucket server). Most of them are tags. Whenever `git fetch` runs, even if fetching a single branch, it calls `git-fetch-pack` underneath, which seemingly has to download entire pack of refs, which is in the size of tens of MBs and takes tens of seconds or several minutes to download for our employees working from distant locations, or even abroad.

Is there any way to optimize `git fetch` so that when fetching a single branch, it does not download entire pack of refs, but instead ref of the single branch being fetched?

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you know the branch name? `git fetch origin <BRANCH_NAME>`

Comment: It is the master branch we tested to reproduce this issue.

Comment: So the testing command that we used is `git fetch origin master`.

Comment: [`git fetch --no-tags origin <BRANCH_NAME>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---no-tags)

Comment: We have no-tags set in fetch options. It doesn't affect fetch-pack actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git has had a long-standing issue with its internal transport protocol: having one Git call up another Git, the *called* Git then lists out *all* its branch and tag names and hash IDs:

> ... seemingly has to download entire pack of refs, which is in the size of tens of MBs and takes tens of seconds or several minutes ...

Since transport protocol version 1 requires that this transaction occur, you're stuck with it as long as your Git uses transport protocol version 1.

[A new protocol version 2 was introduced in Git 2.18 to address this.](https://opensource.googleblog.com/2018/05/introducing-git-protocol-version-2.html)  It can be enabled in versions of Git at this level or later.  There was one fix in Git 2.19.0.  It has become the default in Git 2.26.0, so that it does not need separate enabling; presumably this means any minor niggling bugs are fixed at this point.

To use it easily and automatically, you may install Git version 2.26.0 or later on both "sides" (server and client).

To use protocol version 2 in earlier versions of Git (which all must be at least 2.18), see [this GitLab page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/git_protocol.html).

Comment: Thanks. We're using a very old version on the server.